# Multiple Instances of Auth Variable When Using React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm facing an issue with multiple instances of an auth variable in my React application when using React Context for state management. In every component where I need authentication, I'm using the line const auth = useAuth() to get the authentication state. However, I've noticed that I'm ending up with multiple instances of the auth variable, which is causing unexpected behavior.

Here's a simplified version of how I'm setting up the context and using the useAuth() hook:

```js
// AuthContext.js
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children, auth }) => {
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthContext';
import { useAuth } from '@/hooks/useAuth';
import YourRootComponent from './YourRootComponent';

const App = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  return (
    <AuthProvider auth={auth}>
      <YourRootComponent />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I suspect that the issue is related to how React Context creates a new instance of the auth object for each component that calls the useAuth() hook. As a result, I'm getting multiple copies of the authentication state in memory.

Is there a way to ensure that there's only a single instance of the authentication state shared across all components using React Context? Or am I missing something in the way I'm setting up the context or using the hook?

Any insights or suggestions on how to properly manage the authentication state and avoid multiple instances of the auth variable would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the auth directly inside the provider.

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '@/hooks/useAuth';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const auth = useAuth(); // <= here 

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthContext';
import YourRootComponent from './YourRootComponent';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <YourRootComponent />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```